# how to read matrix text file into r using datatable

Tags: r, read.table

I am having trouble reading a text file that has data formatted in a matrix format as follows:

```
Location Product Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 ... Day1 Day2 Day3
                 Jan  Jan  Jan       ... Feb  Feb  Feb
123      23                 8             9    3
234      25       2    4                            9 
254      87       3
213      56            7                  5
```

It is essentially a time series that has quantities of products by location by day.  I want to eventually convert this into a "sql" table format.

My trouble is when I've tried the following to just skip row 2 and import the rest of the data with the `fill = TRUE`, I don't get the desired result.  The actual counts get shifted to the right and don't align to the first "header" row. I want to combine row 1 and two together to make a date field starting from Day1 in row 1 and then leave empty fields as null or NA.  Then eventually pivot this data to be in the following format:

```
Location Product Period Count
123      23      Jan 1    
234      25      Jan 1    5
234      25      Feb 3    9
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `read.fwf`. (Not sure if data.table's `fread` has such a facility, although ISTR that dplyr has a `read_fwf`.)

Comment: @42- not that I know; from `?fread`: *'fread' is for regular delimited files; i.e., where every row has the same number of columns* & I thought `read_fwf` is from the *readr*-package

Comment: Oh, thanks for correction. Guess I thought all the new stuff was in dplyr.

Comment: @42- nope, I suspect Hadley likes to confuse people: *readr* with replacement functions for the standard `read.*` functions, *readxl* for reading excel files and *haven* for reading files from other statistical packages; my thoughts on that: why 3 packages? why not just one?

Comment: I tried the following and get odd outputs:cjcombo = read.fwf('xxx.txt'
         ,widths= c(122,120,122,122,122)
         ,header = FALSE
         #,sep = "\t"
         ,skip = 0
         , n = 5)

Comment: Those widths are way too large. Try with `c(9, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)` at least with you example with the triple dots removed. And with FWF there is no sep argument, although if the data file has tabs you may need to "auto-expand" then first.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates the auto-position guessing function, `fwf_empty` of pkg:`readr`. I could not get the `read_fwf`-function to accept a text connection argument to the `file` argument, so needed to save the text as a slightly edited version that looks like:

```
Location Product Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4     Day1 Day2 Day3
                 Jan  Jan  Jan  Jan      Feb  Feb  Feb
123      23                 8             9    3
234      25       2    4                            9 
254      87       3
213      56            7                  5
```

The R code:

```
 require(readr)
fwf_empty(file="~/Untitled 4 copy.txt")
$begin
[1]  0  9 17 22 27 32 40

$end
[1]  8 16 21 26 31 36 55

$col_names
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7"

> read_fwf(file="~/Untitled 4 copy.txt", fwf_empty(file="~/Untitled 4 copy.txt"))
Warning: 8 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual
  2  X9 4 chars   3        
  3  X8 4 chars   2        
  3  -- 9 columns 8 columns
  4  X9 4 chars   3        
  5  X3 4 chars   2        
... ... ......... .........
.See problems(...) for more details.
        X1      X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9
1 Location Product Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day1 Day2 Day3
2     <NA>    <NA>  Jan  Jan  Jan  Jan  Feb  Feb  Feb
3      123      23 <NA> <NA>    8 <NA>    9    3 <NA>
4      234      25    2    4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    9
5      254      87    3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6      213      56 <NA>    7 <NA> <NA>    5 <NA> <NA>
```

Then rename the columns and remove the first two lines:

```
> colnm <- paste0( inp[1,], inp[2,])
> colnm
[1] "LocationNA" "ProductNA"  "Day1Jan"    "Day2Jan"    "Day3Jan"   
[6] "Day4Jan"    "Day1Feb"    "Day2Feb"    "Day3Feb"   
> colnames(inp) <- colnm
> inp[-(1:2), ]
  LocationNA ProductNA Day1Jan Day2Jan Day3Jan Day4Jan Day1Feb Day2Feb
3        123        23    <NA>    <NA>       8    <NA>       9       3
4        234        25       2       4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
5        254        87       3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6        213        56    <NA>       7    <NA>    <NA>       5    <NA>
  Day3Feb
3    <NA>
4       9
5    <NA>
6    <NA>
```